# MD5CryptoServiceProvider FIPS compliance

Tags: c#, .net

Any ideas why MD5CryptoServiceProvider isn't throwing a FIPS compliance error. I'm using Win7 and the 3.5 framework. The MS documentation says its not FIPS compliant, but I'm not getting an exception like I was with some of the other algorithms.

--Update--
I get the FIPS exception from a console app, but not my ASP.Net app

Comment: What other crypto methods throw exactly which exception?

Comment: RijndaelManaged was throwing the FIPS exception.  I just tried MD5CryptoServiceProvider from a console app and it throws the exception, just not happening in my Asp.Net app.

Comment: I would be VERY surprised if the same library method throws from a console app but not from an ASP.Net app.  Can you post a very simplified code example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Not much I can show, it throws an exception when the instance is created in the console app, but the same thing doesn't happen in my ASP.net app.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the web site has disabled the FIPS checking using something like this in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Do you have the same behaviour when you run the app in the ASP.NET development web server vs. IIS?

This guy had the opposite problem: [enforceFIPSPolicy flag in web.config doesn't seem to working for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652850/enforcefipspolicy-flag-in-web-config-doesnt-seem-to-working-for-web-application)